# Java, Code Igniter, RoR, DJango web Application Challenge

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, django, programming-languages, codeigniter

This is a framework/programming language challenge. I'm looking for programming language that would be best approach for the next project. I want to get some score (out of 10) of their Time to Develop, Scalability, and Security.

1. Form Builder that will read and write to Database(MYSQL)
2. User Authentication and User Management
3. Easy for API with XML Interface (I don't know if this is correct, what I mean is I want to make the application to export data in to XML, so user could make use of it.)

Thanks!

P.S. If you know some good article on the web related to my question it would be great if you can post it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have any experience with any of these things, so it will probably take you just as long no matter which one you pick.

Comment: Yeah, you assume correctly. Yeah I think so. I think I would just pick 1 framework, I think I would be going for Python/Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say much, using the information you provided. All your desired things can be done with any language and framework.

I would suggest you to pick a framework based on the language you know most. Learning framework is not really a big deal if you know the language, web application patterns and best practices.

However, RoR and Django are famous for speedy development. I am a bit biased towards Django, though. Other good is Groovy on Grails, IMO. Don't know whether it would be appropriate for you to employ that.

So, bottomline is, I am not sure what to recommend you actually.

Comment: Yeah I think I would also be going for Python/Django. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Pick the one that you know very well, they can all do the job. Scalability and security are not tied to language but tied to competence of your developers/you, hardware and "money". anyway, If I have to choose one, I will pick Python/Django.

Comment: yeah, i think so. python/django is a great choice for me. Thanks for the advice